# Why does adding const in front of function parameters give an error?

Tags: c++

```
#include <vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int* find( const vector<int> &vec, int value)
{
    for (int ix = 0; ix < vec.size(); ix ++)
        if (vec[ix] == value)
            return &vec[ix];
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    cout << find(a, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

```
[Running] cd "f:\CPP\VS_Code\" && g++ ch3.cpp -o ch3 && "f:\CPP\VS_Code\"ch3
ch3.cpp: In function 'int* find(const std::vector<int>&, int)':
ch3.cpp:9:20: error: invalid conversion from 'const value_type*' {aka 'const int*'} to 'int*' [-fpermissive]
             return &vec[ix];
```

Comment: The error is clear. Your vector is const, therefore you cannot return a non-const pointer to the data it holds. Why does your function return a pointer? Judging from how you use the function that's probably not what you want.

Comment: `std::vector` and other STL containers generally use something called *iterators* over pointers, such as to reference an object within a vector. The function [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find#Example) provided under the algorithms header does this.

Answer (score 2):

The error is specific, and points you to the return line

```
return &vec[ix];
```

Claiming you are changing a`'const value_type*'` to an `int*`. You have to consider now what's happening:

1. You are returning an address to an element of your vector, which is now marked `const`. So it is a pointer to a `const` value type.
2. On the other hand, the function returns an `int*`, so you could, if this was allowed, take the return value (the constant one) and put it in a regular `int*`. This means you can now change this element, and as a result lose the `const`ness of your vector.

In short - you need to return a `const int*`, and you will only be allowed to use `const` pointers with this function.

On a side note - probably no reason to use pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of current find function below will work.

```
int find(const vector<int> &vec, int value)
{
    for (int ix = 0; ix < vec.size(); ix++)
        if (vec[ix] == value)
            return vec[ix];
    return 0;
}
```

But I am bit confused

- why return int*?
- And What are you expecting from the find method?

  Are you looking for found index? Then return the index.

  ```
  return ix;
  ```

  Or just need to know that it exists? Then change the return type of find to bool and return as below

  ```
  return vec[ix] == value;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because now the value you are returning is of type `const value_type*` while in your code you have mentioned return type as `int*`.

If you changed the argument type you should also change return type as shown below :

```
const int* find( const vector<int> &vec, int value){....}
```

Answer (score 0):

**const vector vec** means that the content of vector 'vec' can't be changed.
When you try to return &vec[i] to int *, you mean that you want to convert the type const int * into the type int * . 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast
Here is something about const_cast, which may be helpful!

Comment: `const_cast` should be used cautiously... it's a dangerous workaround to use in this case.